# jQuery : select box doesn't select default value

Tags: jquery

I've just learned how to change value of a select box. many posts on jQuery provides the statement like:

```
$("#selectBox").val("saab")
```

I tried the above statement, but value of select box won't be changed. Here's my code. I'd like to set value of the select box to `Saab` on html load.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#selectBox").val("saab")
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<select id="selectBox">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>


</body>
</html>
```

What's the problem with my code? Thank you in advance.

Comment: did you include the jquery library file in the head? because it works here http://jsfiddle.net/rhashx2d/

Comment: yes, you can see script tags in the `head` element

Comment: do you get any errors?

Comment: i don't know. where can i check error occurs?

Comment: right click on the site, then click on `inspect element` and then click on `Console`

Comment: console reports parser error. But I don't know what's wrong with my code. isn't my code grammatically right?

Comment: the code is correct but the problem probably lies somewhere else

Comment: i had a unmatched bracket in the script tag. sorry for stealing your time due to my mistake.

Comment: You can also use `selected = "selected"` inside "saab" option tag without any jquery code.

Comment: no problem glad you found the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following code you will what you expect.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#selectBox").val("saab");
});
```

Note: In your code you close **"})."** 2 times, if you remove that one that itself working fine. When ever you working on javascript or jquery try to use ***firebug***. you can easily find out the problem

[Click here to know how to use Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/whatisfirebug)

[how to enable Firebug: click here](http://getfirebug.com/enable)

Comment: Or, in case of Chrome, just press F12